# Is there a way to use relative commands in NBT tags?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know you can use `~` to tell your current location, but when i do this:

```
/summon minecraft:cow ~ ~2 ~ {Leash:{X:36,Y:82,Z:-434},NoAI:1,Age:-25000,Silent:1}
```

and i replace the X,Y,Z with relative coordinates, it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Which version of Minecraft are you playing? Is it 1.12- or 1.13+?

Answer (score 2):

You *can't* use relative coordinates in NBT.

The `X`, `Y`, and `Z` coordinates are raw integers. A `~` is not recognized as an integer symbol and therefore throws an error.

To do this, you must use `/data` to get the player's position, transform the values, and put them onto the cow. For performance reasons, we will use a storage `test:main` for working with our data:

```
data modify storage test:main CowLeash.old set from entity @s Pos
execute store result test:main CowLeash.new.X int 1.0 run data get storage test:main CowLeash.old[0]
execute store result test:main CowLeash.new.Y int 1.0 run data get storage test:main CowLeash.old[1]
execute store result test:main CowLeash.new.Z int 1.0 run data get storage test:main CowLeash.old[2]
data modify entity @e[type=cow,tag=target,limit=1] Leash set from storage test:main CowLeash.new
```

Comment: I'm not the op but I would like a workaround please.

Comment: @f1r3br4nd Two years later, I'm back with a workaround. If you are still looking for one, that is. If not, then I hope I helped *someone* out there.